# defalias derived mode to parent mode

Tags: aliases, derived-mode

I wrote a new major mode [config-general-mode](https://github.com/TLINDEN/config-general-mode), which is derived from `conf-mode`. I like it a lot and want to have it as the default mode for all configuration files. Thus I tried:

```
(defalias 'conf-mode 'config-general-mode)
```

But this doesn't work, I get the error message:

```
Lisp nesting exceeds `max-lisp-eval-depth'
```

Of course I could (and probably will) just associate `*.cfg` and `*.conf` with my mode, but I am curious, if such an alias can be made possible somehow.

Comment: Does adding `#'config-general-mode` to `conf-mode-hook` also incur infinite recursion? (I imagine it would, based on the description by phils.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The nature of a derived mode is that its parent is *called* before the body of the child mode is evaluated<sup>1</sup>.

Therefore if the child becomes its *own* parent (or grandparent, etc...), that causes infinite recursion.

You might attempt to hack your way around this, but I would firmly suggest that you just "don't do that".

<sup>1</sup> For more details on how derived modes work, see "Derived modes, and mode hooks" in https://stackoverflow.com/a/19295380

Answer (score 1):

Here's how you can do what you intended, while avoiding the inf-loop:

```
(defalias 'old-conf-mode (symbol-function 'conf-mode))
(define-derived-mode conf-mode old-conf-mode ...)
```

Note that this is still pretty risky: e.g. it won't work right if `conf-mode` is marked for autoloading when the above code is executed, and it can lead to inf-loops if you re-execute that code a second time.

A safer alternative would be to use `advice-add` to modify `conf-mode` rather than defining a separate `conf-general-mode`.  But it'd still have some quirks (e.g. running `conf-mode-hook` too early).